# Kendo UI Tab Strip

Tags: html, ajax, kendo-ui

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 along with Kendo UI. How do I load `TabStrip` content using Ajax, keeping in mind there are different views (.cshtml).

The last `TabStrip` item (Action, Controller) never loads.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
              .Name("tabstrip")
              .Items(tabstrip =>
              {
                  tabstrip.Add().Text("Dimensions & Weights")
                      .Selected(true)
                      .LoadContentFrom(Url.Content("~/Content/tabstrip/ajax/ajaxContent1.html"));

                  tabstrip.Add().Text("Engine")
                      .LoadContentFrom(Url.Content("~/Content/tabstrip/ajax/ajaxContent2.html"));

                  tabstrip.Add().Text("Chassis")
                      .LoadContentFrom("AjaxLoadedPersonalItem", "Home");
                      //.Content(Html.Action("AjaxLoadedPersonalItem", "Home").ToString());
              })
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have a view call AjaxLoadedPersonalItem under the Views/Home ?

This is the only reason I can see for this not to load.

For example I've just tried the code below and it worked fine

[image]

This is structure I've added to the MVC project

To the controller
[image]

and the respective views

[image]

And this was the result:

[image]

Hope it may help

Answer (score 0):

You would have to ensure that `AjaxLoadedPersonalItem` is a name of a view located in your `Views\Home` folder and has a function in your `HomeController` class, in your Controllers, to return it:

```
public ActionResult AjaxLoadedPersonalItem()
{
    return View();
}
```

Then your view would need to be checked to see if it can be rendered on its own if you went to the page directly by going to `/Home/AjaxLoadedPersonalItem` off of your site's root.  Assuming that is all there and working:

```
tabstrip.Add().Text("Chassis")
    .LoadContentFrom("AjaxLoadedPersonalItem", "Home");
```

should work, as you have, but you can also try loading it as a partial view:

```
tabstrip.Add().Text("Chassis")
    .Content(@<text>@Html.Partial("AjaxLoadedPersonalItem")</text>);
```